R - calculate value by each seperate instance of a variable in a data frame
I have a data frame with multiple instances of variables and their durations. I would like to combine each separate instance of each variable and calculate their duration.
I've provided an example and expected outcome below.

Example data frame:

x <- c("w", "i", "i", "w", "w", "w", "i")
duration <- c(3,4,4,2,1,5,6)

xd <- cbind(x,duration)


What I would like the output to be is:

x_group <- c("w", "i", "w", "i")
duration_group <- c(3,8,8,6)

xd_wanted_outcome<-cbind(x_group,duration_group)

I have tried using group_by - but it groups all instances together.

btw, cbind(x, duration) makes a matrix -- you probably meant data.frame(x, duration)

@JonSpring Yes, I meant to use data.frame(). Thank you for that!

xd <- data.frame(x,duration)

xd |>
  mutate(grp = consecutive_id(x)) |>
  # mutate(grp = cumsum(x != lag(x, 1, ""))) |> # alternative option
  summarize(duration = sum(duration), .by = c(x, grp)) |>
  select(-grp)

  x duration
1 w        3
2 i        8
3 w        8
4 i        6


An option using rle:
with(
  rle(x),
  data.frame(x_group = values,
             duration_group = diff(c(0, cumsum(duration)[cumsum(lengths)])))
)
#>   x_group duration_group
#> 1       w              3
#> 2       i              8
#> 3       w              8
#> 4       i              6


Another base R option
unique(
  transform(
    transform(
      xd,
      grp = with(rle(x), rep(seq.int(lengths), lengths))
    ),
    duration = ave(duration, grp, FUN = sum)
  )
)[names(xd)]

gives
  x duration
1 w        3
2 i        8
4 w        8
7 i        6

